# How to get process instance id in WSO2 BPS

Tags: spring-mvc, wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process

I have a bpel process which is invoked from a spring web application. In my process there is an approval flow. In my web app I want to analyze the process to determine where the process is currently being. For an example : If the process has two approvals to be received I want to know whether the first approval has been returned or likewise. So I want to keep process instance id in my application database. Then I can invoke some admin services to get data about the process.
Is there any way that I can achieve this target ?

And at the same time I want to get confirmed whether there is any admin service to get process status. I know that it is possible to do it with Human tasks.

I'm using WSO2 BPS 3.2.0

Comment: Hey. Couldnt you centralize the whole scope within the BPM tool? Or at least task control...

Comment: @Wanderley , No it isn't possible. According to my business case, it needs to be captured in my web app. Since the approval count is not fixed, it isn't even possible to track the task id.

Answer (score 1):

The instance ID is always available in the variable `$ode:pid`. In order to query a process for state, I would refrain from using the admin API but would rather implement an event handler at the root (or a lower) scope, that listens for something like a `getStatus` operation and uses the PIID as correlation property. It could reply with the approval status. This would be fully BPEL compliant not a hack using the PM API.